# Download sharepoint library document using open Save dialog

Tags: sharepoint

I want to give alert `Do you want to download?` and then show an open / save dialog.  If the user selects save the system should download.  If the user selects open the system should display the contents in Explorer.

I want to download a document from sp library by prompting user to save to some location on the client machine.  I am stuck with the open/save popup functionality.

The code below is prompting to save the .aspx page:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment,filename=" + file);
string filepath = @"C:\Downloads\";
byte[] binfile =file.OpenBinary();
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filepath + file.Name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fstream.Write(binfile, 0, binfile.Length);
fstream.Close();
```

Comment: Please paste some codes and provide where actually you are facing the issue.

Comment: Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment,filename=" + file);string filepath = @"C:\Downloads\"; byte[] binfile =file.OpenBinary();     FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filepath + file.Name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
 fstream.Write(binfile, 0, binfile.Length);
 fstream.Close();                                }

Comment: This is giving a prompt to save the .aspx page.

Comment: It actually gives "open" option in case if file has known file extension. What type of file are you trying to save?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint native functionality to download files:
Redirect to _layouts/download.aspx

See reference here: http://mohitvash.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/sharepoint-download-a-file-programatically/